# Unorganized output from a text file in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, for-loop, output, text-files

I am writing a program in c++ in which I read the data from a text file and then will sort them using sorting algorithm. I am not allow to use file operations to read the input. I am using "for loop" to read all data from the file. The part I am having issue is when I try to print the last part of the file it gets messed up and unorganized. My text file is about 220 lines, and my program is reading it fine until the last part of the file which are my functions.

I should get this after printing:

```
bsort 2015 penalties decr
bsort 2011 yds_per_game incr
bsort range 2010 2015 scrimmage_plays incr
bsort 2012 top_per_game incr
bfind 2013 yds_per_game max
bfind 2015 fum average
bsort range 2011 2013 first_per_game decr
bfind 2014 yds_per_play min
.
.
.
```

but I get this:

```
bsort2015penaltiesdecr
bsort20102015scrimmage_playsincr
2013yds_per_gamemaxbsort20112013first_per_gamedecr
2010third_attmedianbsort20112013pts_per_gamedecr
bsort20132015top_per_gameincr
bsort2014team_nameincr
```

I am using if statements to print this part and here is a part of my code:

```
cin >> c; //Read number of commands
cout << c << endl; //Print the number of commands
cin.ignore();

char** commands =  new char*[c];  //Creat a new array type char to read commands, read the complete line
//Read commands
for(int i = 0; i<c; i++)
{
    commands[i] = new char[256]; //Read the array of the lines
}

string next; //Declare next type string
 for(int i = 0; i <= c - 1; i++){
    cin>>commands[i]; //read the command name
    if(strcmp(commands[i], "bsort") == 0) // check wether it's bsort or not
    {
        cout<<commands[i];
        cin>>next; // if it is bort, we get the next string
        if(next.compare("range") == 0)
        {
            int start_year  , end_year;
            cin>>start_year;
            cout<<start_year;
            cin>>end_year;
            cout<<end_year;
            string field;
            cin>>field;
            cout<<field;
            string order;
            cin>>order;
            cout<<order<<endl;
            cin.ignore();
            bsort(stats,y, start_year, end_year, field, order);
        }
        else
        {
            int year = atoi( next.c_str() );
            cout<<year;
            string field, order;
            cin>>field;
            cin>>order;
            cout<<field;
            cout<<order<<endl;
            cin.ignore();
            bsort(stats, y, year, field, order);
            //Call bsort function by passing only 1 year in the bsort function
        }

    }
   else if(strcmp(commands[i], "bfind") == 0)
    {
        int year;
        cin >> year;
        string field, order;
        cin>>field;
        cin>>order;
        cout<<year;
        cout<<field;
        cout<<order;
        cin.ignore();
        bfind(stats, y, year, field, order);

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Assumption is the mother of all disasters. What happens if your `if - else if` fails? You only check for "bsort" or "bfind", you assume only "bsort" or "bfind" will be the first in line, but clearly it isn't?
Also you've posted part of the code, so we can't help you until you provide a simple and minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add spaces to your output.  If you want a space to appear between two outputs you have to put it there.  You can do that with

```
cout << some_variable << " ";
```

Whenever you have two or more calls to `cout` without a `cin` between then then you need to add some sort of seperator.  In

```
else if(strcmp(commands[i], "bfind") == 0)
{
    int year;
    cin >> year;
    string field, order;
    cin>>field;
    cin>>order;
    cout<<year;
    cout<<field;
    cout<<order;
    cin.ignore();
    bfind(stats, y, year, field, order);

}
```

You output `year`, `field` and `order` without any separation.  If you want them all on one line then you can change it to

```
else if(strcmp(commands[i], "bfind") == 0)
{
    int year;
    string field, order;
    cin year >> field >> order;
    cout << year << " " << field << " " << order;
    cin.ignore();
    bfind(stats, y, year, field, order);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think the problem is missing the spaces between strings since I left it like that on purpose for now. As you see bfind is not printing at all, and bsort is completely messed up. I just don't see the error!

Comment: @Zzhh82 Did you mean `bsort` is not printing?  If so I cannot tell you why as you never showed that code.

Comment: No, "bsort" is actually printing, it is just messed up and unorganized. But "bfind" (last part of my code, you may need to scroll down) is not printing at all. And also thank you for editing my code, I will definitely change it to what you suggested to make it shorter!

Comment: @Zzhh82 I get it.  I changed the answer to show you the `bfind` case.

Comment: Well, it is still not printing. But thank you for your time and answers. :)